# Reachability notification. Where's the right place in my app?

Tags: ios, reachability

I develop an app and some areas are required to be connected to internet generally. Not important how: 3G,Wifi.

So, my question is do I have to use reachability on the main view or I can implement it only in the specific areas where the internet connection is required?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm pretty sure it can be implemented wherever you need it.

All you have to do:

1. Download the classes from [here](https://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/samplecode/Reachability/index.html)
2. Add Reachability.h and Reachability.m to your project
3. Add the SystemConfiguration framework

Then, wherever you want it...

Include it with:

```
#import "Reachability.h"
```

Write a method to call:

```
-(BOOL)reachable {
    Reachability *r = [Reachability reachabilityWithHostName:@"enbr.co.cc"];
    NetworkStatus internetStatus = [r currentReachabilityStatus];
    if(internetStatus == NotReachable) {
        return NO;
    }
    return YES;
}
```

Call it:

```
if ([self reachable]) {
    NSLog(@"Reachable");
}
else {
    NSLog(@"Not Reachable");
}
```

Comment: Updating my answer in a few seconds.

Comment: Updated the answer with instructions.

Comment: Well, I know how to use it. Thank you.